# Error when debugging Ruby code in VSCode (Mac OS X)

Tags: ruby, node.js, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out this new Visual Studio Code (VSCode) Editor while also learning Ruby. Whenever I try to debug a simple ruby program (even Hello World) I receive the following error VSCode

> Error: could not launch 'node' in debug mode

And this is what shows up in my Terminal:

```
/Users/Chixco/Documents/RubyProjects/FirstApp/test.rb:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { puts "Hello!"
                                                               ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:501:10)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:110:15)
```

This is how I have my launch.json file is configured:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
// List of configurations. Add new configurations or edit existing ones.  
// ONLY "node" and "mono" are supported, change "type" to switch.
"configurations": [
    {
        // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
        "name": "Launch test.rb",
        // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
        "type": "node",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "test.rb",
        // Automatically stop program after launch.
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        // Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args": [],
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
        "cwd": ".",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        // Environment variables passed to the program.
        "env": { }
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
        "address": "localhost",
        // Port to attach to.
        "port": 5858
    }
]
}
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

P.S. When I use my Aptana Studio plugin in Eclipse, I don't have any issues.

Comment: Node is a JavaScript engine - you have an error listing JavaScript files (hence `.js` instead of `.rb`). Do you expect a JavaScript engine to execute Ruby code?

Comment: The configuration instructions with regards to debugging in VSCode only refer to the launch.json  config. I need to know what to do specifically in relation to the VSCode editor to get it to debug ruby

Comment: My understanding (very basic, as I haven't spent any significant time with VSCode) is that it's geared to web development with Node.js so I'd hazard it doesn't support debugging ruby code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Code Preview does not support debugging Ruby.
If you would like to see this feature in a future version of VSCode you can vote for it [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code).
In your launch configuration from above you've tried to configure "node" to run your ruby program (which cannot work).

Source: I am a member of the Visual Studio Code Team.

Answer (score 0):

As VS Code already exposes the debugging API and allow us to customize, we can easily create a ruby debugger ourselves.

Currently I'm working on this [VS Code Ruby Debugger](https://github.com/rebornix/vscode-ruby.git), you can download it from [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby). It's still in progress and of coz, non-official.